# How to clear input in edittext with button KOTLIN

Tags: android, kotlin, button, android-edittext

I need to clear editText when button is clicked. in java we use getText or setText but in kotlin I can't find anything.

```
    val email=findViewById<EditText>(R.id.email).apply {
        text= ""
    }
```

I tried using this but ---text=""--- gives me a Type mismatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to get your button id also. Then you should set `setOnClickListener` on your button with clearing the EditText action.

```
val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
val emailEditText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.email)
button.setOnClickListener { emailEditText.setText("") }
```